# Há algum erro no emulador Lollipop 5.1 x86?

Tags: emulador

Esse erro persiste,procurei o Instant run em vários lugares na configuração do Android Studio.

Usando a pesquisa dentro de File-> Settings encontrei somente isso:
Java | Threading issues | Instantiating a Thread with default 'run()' method (desativado).

Claro que não parece ser o local certo. Mas nem a pesquisa consegue achar o menu "Instant run".

Coisas que já fiz.

- Fui no emulador e alterei a Internal Storage para 1800 MB. Também não funcionou.
- Tentei alterar o Boot option de Quick boot para Cold boot. Também não consigo rodar meu app.
- Já fiz "Invalid caches/Restart..."
- Clean Project
- Apaguei C:\Users\fabiano.android\avd\Lollipop_5.0_API_21.avd
- Apaguei C:\Users\fabiano.android\avd\Lollipop_5.1_API_22.avd
- Download novo emulador Android 5.0 Lollipop
- Download novo emulador Android 5.1.1 Lollipop

O emulador tem aviso de pouco espaço na barra de status, aquele ícone de armazenamento. Não importa se aumento a Internal Storage ele mostra que tem pouco espaço! 
O SD card tem 512 MB que deixei como está.

Meu app funciona bem em todos os outros emuladores: 19,23,24,25,26,27,28,29;
O que há de errado no Lollipop 22 e 21 ?

Detalhe, o aviso diz pra desinstalar a aplicação existent, só que não há uma aplicação existente pois acabei de baixar o emulador novo.

```
The device might have stale dexed jars that don't match the current version 
(dexopt error).
In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application

 WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Comment: Caro Fabiano acabei de baixar o Lollipop (nos recomendados do ADT) em x86, funcionou normalmente... Qual versão do Lollip você baixou: **x86 sem Google API**, **x86_64 sem Google API**, **x86 cpm Google API**, **x86_64 com Google API**? Ou baixou o lollipop com ARM? Teu ADT esta atualizado?

Comment: Name: Lollipop_5.0_API_21 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Name: Lollipop_5.1_API_22   CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)    image.androidVersion.api: 22  tag.id: google_apis.

Comment: Resolvi. Almentei a memoria interna do emulador para 5000 MB. Agora o programa roda.

Comment: Deu certo uma ou duas vezes. Depois tive queo com aumentar a memória interna. Já tó com 8000 MB e ainda da problema de espaço insuficiente. Reinstalei com 1600 MB que é o dobro que vem na instalação, e mesmo assim da problema de espaço!